# What does it mean to have 'an offensive ceiling'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image: Source]
As mentioned in title,I couldn't figure out what the writer intends to say by this.

Comment: I think it's ceiling as *maximum level one can reach*. The term *Skill Ceiling* is largely used in esports along with *skill cap* and *skill floor*.

Comment: If the ceiling is the max, then the higher ceiling is incorrect?

Comment: @Anubhav Singh: No, the ceiling is one's maximum level. Everyone has one, everyone has a maximum level he can reach. But Irving's is the highest of all offensive ceilings.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh Some players have a higher ceiling than others, are capable of scoring more points: no player's ceiling is higher than Irving's.

Comment: If Kyrie Irving wrote obscenities onto his ceiling and the height of his room was bigger than that of somebody else doing that, he'd have a *higher offensive ceiling*. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got from answer from comments:

By MadWard -
 No, the ceiling is one's maximum level. Everyone has one, and everyone has a maximum level he can reach. But Irving's is the highest of all offensive ceilings.

By StoneyB -
Some players have a higher ceiling than others, are capable of scoring more points: no player's ceiling is higher than Irving's